# Como colocar links de redes sociais para compartilhar o link da pagina de um post?

Tags: html, css, html5, asp.net

Eu estou com uma dúvida. Eu não entendo muito de ASP.Net, porém um amigo meu pediu uma ajuda pra implementar uns botões de rede social no site de TCC dele. O TCC dele é um portal de notícias, como qualquer outro.

Ele gostaria de colocar, em cada página de post algo do tipo:

[image: Botões de redes sociais para compartilhamento.]

Juntamente com o botãozinho do WhatsApp.

O intuito é compartilhar cada pagina de post, ou seja, tem postagem x, eles compartilham o link x, e na postagem y, eles compartilham o link y da postagem y.

Obrigado desde já!!

Comment: Em cada post individualmente? ou em lista?

Comment: Em cada post individualmente!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada rede social funciona de uma forma diferente. No caso do Twitter, você pode usar algo como esse código javascript:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
class="twitter-share-button" 
data-url="http://seusite.com/noticia/id" 
data-via="seuarroba" data-related="seuarroba" 
data-hashtags="minhaHashtag">
Tweet
</a>   
<script>!function(d,s,id){
  var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
  if(!d.getElementById(id)){
    js=d.createElement(s);
    js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
  }
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
```

basta substituir os valores dos parâmetros 'data-url' pelo link da notícia, 'data-via' pelo perfil do twitter referente ao site, data-related pelo perfil a ser indicado (para que outras pessoas o sigam) e 'data-hashtags' pelas hashtags (se houver)